# firefoxでIPアドレスを入れるとgoogle検索になってしまう。

Tags: firefox

現在仮想環境上にて3台のWebサーバ（A,B,C）を立てました。（centos7を使用）この時に各サーバが正常に動いているかの確認の為、サーバAにてfirefoxのアドレスバーに`http:x.x.x.x/`（`x.x.x.x`はサーバBのIPアドレス）を入れると`http:x.x.x.x/`のgoogleでの検索結果が出てしまいます。
curlコマンドを使っての検証や`systemctl`を使っての検証は可能なのですが、firefoxを使用しての検証は出来ないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結論から言うとvmwareでfirefoxを使用していましたが、:では無く;で検索をしていました。；では無く:とした所正常にアクセスが出来ました。
vmwareの英語キーボード入力の問題が根本的な問題でした。

Answer (score 2):

`http://x.x.x.x` の間違いではないでしょうか。正しくは `http://` で、あなたが入力した値はスラッシュ２つが抜けています。

Comment: `http://x.x.x.x` で試しても同様でした。